# En Colombia, ¿qué significa "vaina"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, significado, coloquialismos, colombia

Oigo a veces a los colombianos (de Bogotá, los que conozco) diciendo:

> Uy qué vaina

Yo lo interpeto como un "uy qué cosas", en un contexto en el que algo es complicado o puede dar problemas:

> Uy qué vaina, me dejé las llaves del coche en casa

Sobre *vaina*, explica [Bogotalogo](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94635822/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital):

> Término empleado para aludirse a un objeto o situación cualquiera cuyo nombre no se recuerda o se desconoce. Problema de difícil resolución. Conflicto.

Pero así y todo sigo teniendo dudas sobre su uso: ¿es solamente coloquial? ¿se usa en otros países? ¿tiene alguna acepción más además de la que indico?

Comment: La respuesta de @CarlosAlejo es suficiente, pero mis dos centavos. Para traducir _vaina_ del Colombiano al español solo se reemplaza por _cosa_. Con respecto al uso son los dos que mencionas y si quieren la receta del cóctel Chileno y los demas significados en América Latina ver este [enlace](http://www.asihablamos.com/www/significado/palabra/vaina)

Comment: @DGaleano, debes ver este video, un [cómico significado de vaina "en el 4:06"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpQH_xtMzD0).

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Excelente. Gracias. Fedorqui va a sacar muchas preguntas de ese video jajaja.

Comment: Esta palabra en realidad ha sido tomada en el español andino de Colombia quizás porque es propia de la costa (donde se habla español caribeño como en Venezuela, Puerto Rico, Dominicana, Cuba, Florida). En realidad es propia del caribeño pero fue aceptada en la zona Andina de Colombia. Al igual que "Pana", la cual también es del caribeño y se cree que ha sido por la influencia Venezolana.

Comment: En españa se refiere a un vago

Comment: @Iria ¿en qué zona? Nunca lo oí mencionar así

Comment: en la Castilla profunda, se lo he oído mucho a mis padres. 'Menudo vaina está hecho!'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la RAE, el término *[vaina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bGoiGhS)* tiene dos acepciones para América Latina que coinciden con lo que propones:

> f. *Am. Cen., Chile, Col., Ec., Perú, R. Dom. y Ven.* Contrariedad, molestia.
>
> f. *Col., Cuba, Ec., Guat., Hond., Nic., Pan., Perú y Ven.* Cosa no bien conocida o recordada.

La acepcion de contrariedad encaja en el ejemplo de las llaves del coche. En todo caso, no dice que su uso sea coloquial. La que sí que es coloquial es la expresión "ni de vaina", también usada en Colombia y otros países y significando "de ninguna manera".

Como curiosidad, aquí en Andalucía usamos la última acepción, que también es coloquial:

> m. y f. coloq. Persona poco seria e irresponsable.

Comment: Chile aparece mencionado en la acepción "contrariedad, molestia", pero te puedo asegurar que aquí nunca lo usamos con ese significado. Tal vez algún abuelito, no sé. En Chile una vaina es un trago (cóctel) para damas, hecho con algún vino dulce, espuma de huevo batido, mucha azúcar y canela en polvo.