# ¿Como adquirió la palabra "vaina" el significado "cosa"?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, colombia

*Vaina* significa la funda de una espada. Pero en Colombia y otros países americanos significa también "cosa":

[En Colombia, ¿qué significa "vaina"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/en-colombia-qu%C3%A9-significa-vaina)

¿Cómo ha adquirido la palabra este significado?

Comment: Apostaría que tiene el mismo origen genital que la _wevá_ que usamos los chilenos para decir casi cualquier cosa.

Comment: Ese significado debe tener unas raices historicas muy profundas y no por tiempo si no por que se usa en muchos contextos, y no, no es equivalente a *wea*, para eso tenemos gonorrea jajaja.

Comment: ¿Esto es de ayuda?: https://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/CMS-16232615 Leyendo algunos diccionarios de latín, noto que _vagina_ ya tenía en tiempos clásicos el significado de funda, estuche o envoltorio. El salto a «cosa» no estaba tan lejos, como se explica en el artículo.

Comment: No es solo Colombia. Se usa mucho en la República Dominicana.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente evoluciono durante los tiempos en que la mayoria de la poblacion  se enfocaba en la agricultura. Como han listado en el link de Colombia, una de las definiciones formales de acuerdo a la RAE es " Cáscara tierna y larga en que están encerradas las semillas de algunas plantas".  Me suena parecido a "tetunte" en El Salvador que se utiliza de manera similar. Tambien originaria de agricultura. La mayoria de personas lo asocian con un pedazo de tierra.